# How can I use cognito to create user accounts, but a different service for verification?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, twilio, amazon-cognito, plivo

I am building an app that will be using Plivo or Twilio for user interaction and input.

I wanted to use AWS Cognito for user management, but for verification, they say a user must verify email or phone number.

I wanted to have the user interaction and verification come from the same phone number, so is there a way to set this up in Node.js somehow, where a text to a Plivo/Twilio number reroutes to AWS Cognito for verification?

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59039529/2579733

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the custom auth flow to achieve this. Take a look on a example article we have here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/

The idea is that you will explicitly do the calls you want to Twilio/Plivo from the lambda function.

Cognito UserPools does not intergrade out of the box with a third party.
And offers its own notification mechanism through SNS and SES services.
I would consider  this option as well in your position.

Comment: so I would add sms sending logic in pre signup. what should I set in response verifyPhone ? as I cannot accept the signup nor deny it but wait till otp is send back by user

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the document, it seems that it is now possible to send emails and SMS using a third party.
It is unknown when it was released.

Custom Sender Lambda Trigger

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html

Custom SMS Sender Lambda Trigger

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sms-sender.html

Custom Email Lambda Trigger

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html