# Configure Cognito to send emails through third party such as SendGrid the proper way

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have tried to invoke the custom message function to send emails through SendGrid, well it worked but I don't have a way to stop AWS from sending through their emails. I have tried to set the `messageAction` to "SUPPRESS" but another problem arises. There is no such support for self-registration since `messageAction` is only for adminCreateUser function. Did I miss something or am I not doing this properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Custom Sender Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html) is the way to use 3rd party notification service providers.

Cognito docs are lacking at the moment (steps are missing, Lambda code has to be fixed after copying from the example, no instructions of how to deploy with CloudFormation, ...).

**High level overview of the steps:**

1. Create a symmetric KMS key.
2. Create a Lambda function. Grant Lambda permission to `kms:Decrypt` the key. Pass the key ARN as the environment variable.
3. Create a User Pool and a User Pool Client. For the pool, configure `LambdaConfig` providing Lambda and KMS Key ARNs.
4. In the code, decrypt the notification code using the key passed in the env variables.
5. Send the notification code using the 3rd party (e.g. Twilio Sendgrid) API.

**Tooling (as of March 2021):**

- Cognito Console does not support new triggers
- AWS CLI supports new triggers
- CloudFormation docs say triggers are not supported, but in reality it works
- Terraform does not support setting new triggers yet (there's a workaround)

I've blogged about the process of setting up the Custom Email Lambda Trigger with CloudFormation and Terraform: [Send AWS Cognito emails with 3rd party ESPs](https://www.maxivanov.io/send-aws-cognito-emails-with-3rd-party-esps/).

Comment: thanks for writing this out, it seems like AWS want us to crowdsource the docs for cognito these days

Comment: Now available in Terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/16502 https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool#lambda_config

Answer (score 5):

It seems that now Cognito is starting to support this.

Cognito provides two Lambda triggers `CustomEmailSender` and `CustomSMSSender` to enable third-party email and SMS notifications.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Source from AWS Cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html)</sub>

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated This is an Answer. It's saying that it's supported now. The link is just refrence.

Comment: @Scratte I still didnt like the answer.... is my edit ok?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito recently started the support for allowing users to send [emails via third party](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html). You will have to do this via a lambda so here are the steps:

1. Create a lambda which will be calling your email provider to send the email/pass the data
2. Give kinesis permissions to the lambda function role that you created
3. Create a symmetric KMS key
4. Add the lambda function role to users list of key
5. Add KEY_ID and KEY_ALIAS in the lambda preferable as an env variable
6. Give permission to lambda function to invoke cognito using cli

   aws lambda add-permission --function-name YOURLAMBDAARN --statement-id "CognitoLambdaInvokeAccess" --action lambda:InvokeFunction --principal cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
7. Setup your cognito
   *This will reset cognito settings so have a look at what was enabled first*

   aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id yourpoolid --lambda-config PreSignUp="oranyofyourtriggers",CustomEmailSender="{LambdaVersion="V1_0",LambdaArn="yourlambdaarn"}",KMSKeyID="yourkeyarn"

the above command would have reset cognito so all the triggers if any that were being used previously will have to be set
now in MFA and verifications, in what attributes to verify select email (and sms settings and give a role if that was used previously) and save those changes