# Integrate Twillio with AWS Cognito to send MFA verification code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito to manage users in my application and all the users are MFA enabled. So users receive verification codes when they are signing up and signing in. Due to spending limits and other reasons, I'm wondering if I can use Twillio or any other 3rd party integrated, to send out those SMS messages to users. Very much appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Something like this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/44594700/4636715

Comment: @vahdet exactly. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the document, it seems that it is now possible to send emails and SMS using a third party. It is unknown when it was released.

Custom Sender Lambda Trigger
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html

Custom SMS Sender Lambda Trigger
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sms-sender.html

Custom Email Lambda Trigger
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html